# Getting past the geth cannon

Tags: mass-effect-2

In Project Overlord How do you get past the Geth cannon on Vulcan station? All I have is the cluncky Hammerhead. Once the cannon charges and fires even if the Hammerhead is in air it gets shot down.

[image]

How do you get past the Geth cannon on Vulcan station? Should I try and destroy the little ones first or the giant dome (not visible in above pic first)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This part of the mission is a bit tricky, but it's rather easy once you know what you're doing. Use the enemy's weapon against him/itself.

> So just hover around near a generator and once it starts Shooting move away. It will still hit the generator and take it out, despite the force field. You can just shoot the shields yourself, but the cannon is doing a lot more damage.

Comment: you call the Hammerhead unresponsive, you obviously didn't drive the Mako!